# Display settings lost on reboot

Tags: display, nvidia

I have 2 monitors hooked up to my 1080. One 24" 1920x1200 and one 2560x1440 with 144hz.

But when I reboot I have to reapply the settings for the displays. This includes changing the mosaic, the monitors are on the wrong side. The 27" monitor also reverts back to 60hz, although I can set it fine to 144hz manually.

I've tried a lot of things today, including changing .config/monitors.xml,  xorg.conf and .nvidia-settings-rc. I've also tried running nvidia-settings as sudo, and save the configuration that way, but no luck. From what I can tell, this is a fairly common problem, but none of the answers have worked for me. It seems like Xorg pulls the default window config from a random place when the system boots.

Any ideas?

Comment: thanks for your question. Can you add vendor and model of your card in order to help others to answer you?